# can't run spyder when i use conda upgrade --all

Tags: conda, spyder, geopandas

i'm a beginner in python so i hope you could help me with this.

I'm trying to install the package geopandas. When i try to install geopandas with: 
`conda install -c conda-forge geopandas` i get an error. The error is a lot of collision packages that conda can't solve it even with conda forge. 
So i tried `conda upgrade --all` before i use `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`. Then geopandas install
properly but when i want to open the spyder i get this error:

```
(base) C:\Users\jcrav>spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jcrav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jcrav\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\jcrav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 201, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "C:\Users\jcrav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 53, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "C:\Users\jcrav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 41, in check_qt
    import qtpy
  File "C:\Users\jcrav\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

PD: i have windows 10 64bits

Comment: can you give us the output of `conda install -c conda-forge  spyder=4.1.2 --dry-run`

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by using pip to install the following packages: `pyqt5`, `pyqt5-sip`, `pyqtwebengine`, `ptyprocess` & `helpdev`.

`Conda` or `conda-forge` don't seem to have `pyqt5` so that's why I had to use `pip`.

It could be that you already have `pyqt5-sip` & `pyqtwebengine` on your `conda`. This was the case for me and I had to uninstall those first before installing the packages above.

This was for `Python=3.6`, `Spyder=4.1.4` and in a clean `mini-conda` environment.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a very bad advice because conda and pip packages are binary incompatible. What you need to do is run `conda install -f pyqt=5`.